# Как создать дубликат проекта в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

В Android Studio нет функции Save As...

Имеется проект Android Studio. Нужно продолжать его разработку дальше, но на данном этапе нужно сделать дубликат и разрабатывать новый проект в другом направлении.
Можно ли как-то вручную провернуть такую авантюру?

Comment: Посмотри гит. Он позволяет сделать что тебе надо. А точнее ветки у гита

Comment: Про гит я знаю. Но хотелось бы получать не новые ветки, а полностью независимые автономные дубликаты проекта. Например, сделать шаблон проекта (достаточно сложный, что-бы повторять его каждый раз с нуля) и затем на основе этого шаблона делать другие проекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 3 способа, которые нужно использовать в зависимости от того, что вам в итоге надо.

1. Просто скопируйте содержимое проекта через проводник в другую папку - вот и полная копия проекта. Годится в том случае, если 2 проекта будут теперь совсем разными и в них почти не будет одинакового кода.
2. Если надо делать некоторые изменения в основном проекте, при этом сохраняя связь с нынешним, то есть 2 пути.

   2.1. Использовать Git и его систему веток - в отдельной ветке вы получите полную копию вашего кода и у вас останется возможность подтягивать изменения из основной версии проекта. Подойдёт, например, если вам надо поменять немного кода и/или добавить пару экранов, которых нет в изначальной версии.

   2.2. Использовать `flavor` механизм - позволяет получать разные сборки проекта с разным кодом в определённых местах. Например, можно подставить разные адреса серверов в разные сборки.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне бы подошел первый способ. И, в итоге, я именно так и сделала. Но нужно сделать еще и полный ринейм. Чтобы не осталось следа от старого названия проекта. По большому счету, раз можно просто скопировать папку, то вопрос сводится к следующему: Какие файлы в проекте-дубликате необходимо переименовать. По списку. Я переименовала только файл .iml, но этого оказалось недостаточно.

Comment: Тут уж опять надо смотреть что вам нужно) Как минимум надо пакет переименовать, т.к. он используется для определения уникальности приложения. Т.е. два приложения с одним пакетом по умолчанию будут перезаписывать друг-друга при установке на девайс.

Comment: Нужно просто список мест в проекте, где следует изменить старое название проекта. Начиная с самой папки с проектом и заканчивая самым последним файлом. При этом, чтобы переименование никак не повлияло на работоспособность проекта. Итак: основная папка, пакет, файл .iml, и какие файлы дальше? Переименовывать можно прямо в проводнике, или необходимо рефакторить в Android Studio? Я просто думала, что подобная процедура уже расписана и надеялась получить ее описание...

Comment: @AliceMagic, переменовае папки да - в проводнике надо сделать. Файл `.iml`, вроде, можно просто удалить и он при открытии проекта студией сам сгенерируется, может там и править ничего не придётся. Остальное лучше через студию править через `refactor->rename` - так оно само везде поправит импорты в коде (так можно и пакет и имена классов поправить).  Останется только проверить `build.gradle(module app)` на предмет `applicationId` и манифест (тут, скорее всего, рефакторинг через студию всё сам переименует корректно, в отличие от `applicationId` в `build.gradle`)

Comment: Как я и предполагала, все поползло уже при попытке переименования пакета (через refactor->rename). Причем, не только в проекте-дубликате, но и в исходном проекте. Начисто отбило охоту дальнейших экспериментов))) Не зря все-таки отсутствует SaveAs

Comment: @AliceMagic, ну да, там есть некоторые опасности) Вроде бы оно лучше работает, если переименовывать пакет по частям, начиная с нижнего уровня. Т.е. если пакет `com.example.myapp`, то сначала надо `myapp` переименовать, а `com` в самом конце.